# copy range until last row value equal 0

Tags: vba, excel, select, copy-paste

I am trying to copy and paste a range of cells using VBA/Macro. I need a code to select a range of cells based on on the sum of the last row. The number of rows may change but the columns will always be 9 and end at "I".

[image: Image of my excel sheet/example]

Although row 7 has no data, I need to look past this and continue (Possibly until 3 consecutive rows of 0's). I have highlighted the area I would like to copy/select.

This may not be the best process in achieving the result, I welcome any and all help. My apologies for not including a code, but i have no idea on how to achieve this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula should give you the row number of the last value in column I that is `>0`: `=LOOKUP(2,1/(I:I>0), ROW(I:I))` and you could use that in VBA with the `Evaluate()` function.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FindLastValueGreaterZeroInColumnI()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Evaluate("=LOOKUP(2,1/(I:I>0), ROW(I:I))")

    Dim CopyRange As Range
    Set CopyRange = ws.Range("A1", ws.Cells(LastRow, "I"))

    Debug.Print CopyRange.Address
End Sub
```

You can then use that to copy and paste your range.

---

**Explanation why this formula works:**

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(I:I>0), ROW(I:I))
```

1. Lets assume the following example data in column I:

   ```
   {28, 28, 29, 0, 30, 30, 28, 0, 0}
   ```
2. `I:I>0` returns a array of `True` and `False` where it is `True` for values `>0` otherwise `False`, so it returns the following array:

   ```
   {True, True, True, False, True, True, True, False, False}
   ```
3. Because `True = -1` and `False = 0` the `1/(I:I>0)` returns either `-1` or error `#Div/0!`, so it returns the following array:

   ```
   {-1, -1, -1, #Div/0!, -1, -1, -1, #Div/0!, #Div/0!}
   ```
4. `LOOKUP(lookup_value, lookup_vector, [result_vector])` If we now lookup the `lookup_value = 2` and the `LOOKUP` function can't find the `lookup_value`, the function matches the largest value in `lookup_vector` that is less than or equal to `lookup_value`. In this case it will find the last `-1`.
   And because the `result_vector = ROW(I:I)` it will return the row number of it, which is the row number of the last value `>0`.

Comment: Thank you for this, using this i managed to get what i needed. Really appreciate the help.